# Is the text within an online Adobe Flash application rendered server-side?

Tags: flash

When I visit that website containing a Flash app (with text displayed in the app), will the Flash app send text and font info to the client and let the client render it or is it already pre-rendered server-side? Can the text be easily parsed client-side (without image scraping)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Flash app itself contains the 'embedded' vector font outlines (called Glyphs). During publish of the Flash file and the author can choose which glyphs to export.**

For example, if the Flash contains a text label that says 'Hello' that is only used once and implemented as static text, the author can choose just to export the 'H', 'e', 'l', and 'o' glyphs.

However, if the author has dynamic text on a Flash, they would likely choose to export all of the glyphs available, or choose ranges of glyphs to export during publish.

Regarding collecting text, and noting the above, the text *does* exist in plaintext where used in Actionscript (the strings are maintained even if the Flash file is encrypted) and also from the stage (where implemented statically). Both can be collected by a SWF Decompiler. A quick Google search yielded [this Adobe Air application on code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/flash-decompiler/) for doing so: